# Remove Unknown ATA User Password

Tags: passwords, ata

On a Hitachi 2.5" disk, is there a way to remove an unknown ATA user password? I have access to MHDD, atapwd, etc, but there's not much I can do without actually *knowing* the password. Erasing the disk is fine, I don't need its contents.

Comment: Do you have a device that unlocks the drive in the process of talking to it (The original XBox did the same thing and there where workarounds the ATA password, but you had to boot the drive from the XBox, attach it to a computer without unpowering it, then boot the computer). Where is this drive from?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The drive is from a laptop. The user password was set on accident by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the master password to unlock (or erase) the drive.

Note that hard drives often ship with factory-set master passwords; you may find one by searching the Internet for your drive model number.

If you're unable to obtain either the user password or the master password, you will be unable to use the drive at all.

Comment: Guess I'm SOL then- I can't find the master password for this model. Thanks for your answer.